# Java Spark unable to process wholeTextFiles

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to `Spark API` and learning along the way.

I have multiple files in a hadoop directory which I am reading using wholeTextFiles to create `JavaPairRDD<String, String>`. Program is in Java.

My requirement is to process list of files in a directory and achieve following output:

> file-path, word
>
> file-path, word
>
> file-path, word

...

This is basically word content of files with the corresponding file name (or path) paired as `<String, String>`.

I tried following however casting from tuple2 to Iterable is not allowed (failed at run time):

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf()) ;

JavaPairRDD<String, String> files = sc.wholeTextFiles(args[0]);

JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> file_word = files
.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String,String>, Tuple2<String,String>>()
{
public Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>> call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple) 
{
 return (Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>>) new Tuple2<String, Iterable<String>>(tuple._1(), Arrays.asList(((String) tuple._2()).toLowerCase ().split("\\W+")));
}
});
```

I am using `Java 8`, `Hadoop2` with `Spark 2.2.0`.

(By looking at other questions here I can understand writing this in scala is easier however I did not find relevant answer for Java)

Looking for solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you are trying to cast an Tuple2 into an Iterable, which cannot work.

Since you are using java8, you can write this with a lambda expression which will make things much more compact:

```java
JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd = sc
            .wholeTextFiles("path_to_data/*")
            .flatMapValues(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split("\\W+")));
```

Note that I am using `flatMapValues` instead of `flatMap` because you only need to process the second value of the tuple.

In case you are curious, with `flatmap` you could have done it by mapping each word of your file to a tuple (fileName, word):

```java
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> rdd2 = sc
            .wholeTextFiles("path_to_data/*")
            .flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(x._2.split("\\n"))
                    .stream()
                    .map(w -> new Tuple2<>(x._1, w))
                    .iterator());
```

`flatMapValues` simply enables you to do that with less code ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I am able to use it.